# IBM Containers and the DevOps Pipeline

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops, jazz

Trying to get started with this..

I created an image (Nodejs) and pushed it to Bluemix. In Bluemix, I created a container and this worked.

I then created a project in jazz... and used the DevOps pipeline (IBM Container service) to build the app.  What I want to do is automate the build and deploy of this app.

Now.. what should I put as the image name?  I would have thought that it was the image I had already pushed.. but perhaps not.  I then changed it to something like 'mynewapp' but that doesn't work either.

The error I get when I use an existing image is: (Image name is test920)  Not sure why it has added a tag of 12...

```
The desired image repository name will be registry.ng.bluemix.net/jytestcontainer/test920:12
Initialization complete
Number of images: 0 and Image limit: 5
The number of images are less than the image limit
Init runtime of 3m 10s
total 12

Starting build script
No unit tests cases have been checked in
Building registry.ng.bluemix.net/jytestcontainer/test920:12
zipped tar size: 1185166
Posting 1185166 bytes... It may take a while...
Command failed with container cloud service
{
    "code": "IC5000E", 
    "description": **"Sorry, an error occurred on our side. Please reference the problem using the provided incident ID",** 
    "incident_id": "b4b88aeb12e5a4d9", 
    "name": "DefaultMessage", 
    "rc": "500", 
    "type": "General"
}
```

When I use a new image name -- one that does not exist.. I get:

```
Building registry.ng.bluemix.net/jytestcontainer/**nodecontainer**:15
zipped tar size: 1185855
Posting 1185855 bytes... It may take a while...
Command failed with container cloud service
{
    "code": "IC5000E", 
    "description": "Sorry, an error occurred on our side. Please reference the problem using the provided incident ID", 
    "incident_id": "b520b2ea4a115bbd", 
    "name": "DefaultMessage", 
    "rc": "500", 
    "type": "General"
}
"ice build --pull --tag registry.ng.bluemix.net/jytestcontainer/nodecontainer:15 /home/jenkins/workspace/3f72adfe-59e3-b729-ef87-6316c8d67561/806f147e-9244-4b69-849e-abce3b0def1b" did not return successfully.
```

So the question is... Does this process build a new image first?  if so.. why doesn't it work with an image name that does not exist?

If it requires an existing image.. why does it use a tag that does not exist?

Any pointers are appreciated....

Cheers

Comment: Note: Checked the build script...

Building registry.ng.bluemix.net/jytestcontainer/test920:12

The '12' is the build version -- not the tagname.

Answer (score 1):

These [sample scripts](https://github.com/Osthanes/deployscripts) worked fine for me. You can check the usage in this public [sample](https://hub.jazz.net/project/chemi/Demo4Bluemix%20(Docker)/overview).